# Jetty.xml access static content

Tags: java, xml, jetty

I'm trying to access static content on a server where a war is deployed using jetty.xml configuration. I used a ResourceHandler, it worked but then I can't access the website content anymore. I tried adding a DefaultHandler but I still can't access the content on "/". Do I have to add a specific handler for other requests?

Here's my jetty.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <Set name="ThreadPool">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

  <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStore"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />//etc/mykeystore.keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">xxxxxxx</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">xxxxxxxx</Set>
  </New>

  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <Arg><Ref id="sslContextFactory" /></Arg>
        <Set name="Port">443</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="AcceptQueueSize">100</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
           <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                  <Set name="contextPath">/img</Set>
                  <Set name="handler">
                      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
                          <Set name="directoriesListed">false</Set>
                          <Set name="resourceBase">/home/img</Set>
                      </New>
                  </Set>
              </New>
          </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jetty 9, just make a directory in `${jetty.base}/webapps/` and put your content there.

For example, if you created

```
 ${jetty.base}/webapps/static/css/main.css
```

then that will be served from the `/static/` context, making the following a valid access to that content.

```
http://localhost:8080/static/css/main.css
```

This is known as a static resource deployment, and is part of the default deployment techniques present on Jetty's default deployment configuration.

You can also use a context deployable xml to declare any arbitrary static content you want, in any location on disk that you want.

See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/static-content-deployment.html